# c3p0 - hibernate - mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, c3p0

- hibernate 3.6.8 final
- c3p0 jar that came with hibernate 3.6.8 package -> c3p0-0.9.1.jar

  1
  15
  40
  0
  5
  2

The app seems to be working fine, however I get massive log calls with the following stacktrace:

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor38.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:152)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1074)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1061)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1796)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:620)
```

Any information on how to remove that INFO log would be very much helpful thanks!

**UPDATE:** Is this a critical error? Or can should I just ignore it?

Comment: It says `this web application instance has been stopped already` so I think that is a critical error. Do you see this log when you try to stop your server? Or can anyone or anytool access your app server and stop it? Or do you see this when undeploying and deploying your application?

Comment: it happens on undeployment as well ...

Comment: Did you have a chance to look into the possible cause and solution I proposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I switched to boneCP, c3p0 does not really seem to work for java6!!!

Comment: What does "c3p0 does not work for java6" exactly mean? Please elaborate.

Comment: sorry cherouvim for not referencing, but it seems that c3p0 is broken under java6. I read it somewhere, but don't have time to backtrace that. boneCP was the best alternative fixing the problem ...

Comment: c3p0 is not "broken under java6". it doesn't yet support JDBC4 features (and so can't be built from source under Java6, as it doesn't implement new versions of the interfaces). as long as your app sticks with JDBC operations as defined under the 3.0 version of the spec -- that is, if you don't use the features that were added as of Java6 -- c3p0 works fine.

Answer (score 1):

After a search on the web regarding this issue, I found some similar issues reported by several people. All of them point to a common problem: Threads. Basically, if you start new threads in your application (either in your code or by using a third party tool like `Quartz`, you have to make sure that all of the threads are stopped appropriately when the application is undeployed from the server. Here are some quotes from the searches:

Mikolaj Rydzewski [wrote](http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/Illegal-access-this-web-application-instance-has-been-stopped-already-td2139695.html):

> It looks like after webapp's instance has been undeployed, background quartz thread wants to do something and then exception occurs.

Another (and better explanation) on [jspwiki.org](http://www.jspwiki.org/wiki/StupidQuestions):

> It is possible that this is caused by Tomcat unsuccessfully reloading the web application. The app is unloaded, but all threads don't get shut down properly. As a result, when the threads try to run, they get clobbered by the fact that Tomcat has shut down its classloader, and an error is logged.

So, in order to solve this issue you have to make sure all threads started by your application will be stopped at application undeployment (or redeployment, it's the same). You can do this by registering a `ServletContextListener` to your application server and stopping your threads inside `contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent)` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using log4j, change your logging settings to something like this (the word ERROR replace INFO) :

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, file, stdout
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

They are located in the the log4j.properties file in yr project.